# Make [ballerinalang] a synonym of [ballerina]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[ballerina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ballerina) and [ballerinalang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ballerinalang) share the same wiki content: [ballerina](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ballerina/info), [ballerinalang](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ballerinalang/info)

Comment: The sad part is that both wiki's seem to be [plagiarized from the main website](https://ballerina.io/philosophy/) and that is not only not allowed but also never leads to a tag wiki that is actual useful for the few users that read those things. I will not edit the wiki's right now but someone has to come-up with something better.